# How can I read and write to the serial buffer in the same Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, usb, pyserial

I'm having a problem understanding how serial works.

I am trying to write a looping script that generates a code in Python, reads the serial buffer for a six digit code entered into the Arduino keypad, sends it back to Python, checks it against a code in an postgreSQL database and returns a value (1 for match, and 0 for no match). I want to send the binary value to the Arduino and trigger a linear servo. When I run the Python loop that I wrote, it functions how I would expect, until I get to the value returned from the SQL database. The value does not seem to write to the serial buffer, and so the Arduino loop never triggers the linear servo. For simplicity of testing, I am generating a code for the keypad locally every time the loop runs.

At first, I was using the keypad.h function waitForKey(), which is blocking. I thought that the blocking was keeping the Arduino loop from registering the updated value and operating the servo. I changed it to getKey(), but the function is still not working. I have tried different encoding methods and writing different types of data (characters and numbers), but nothing seems to work.

Here is the most relevant section of the Python code:

```py
if (txStage == '0'):
        #genCode = search_ChatValue("access_code","demo") #Find the value in the database table
        time.sleep(10)
        while (ser.inWaiting() > 0):
            codeDigit = ser.readline(9)
            codeDigit = codeDigit.decode()
            codeDigit = codeDigit[0:6]
        ser.flush()
        print(codeDigit)
        attemptCode(codeDigit, "demo") #check the entered code against the database code
        doorVer = codeResult("demo") #Check if the code was correct
        print(doorVer)
        if (doorVer == "Success! You may now access your SafeDrop."): #if the code is correct
            lockVer = '1' #variable to be sent to the Arduino
            print("lock status is: " + str(lockVer))
            ser.flush() #flush the serial buffer to ensure it is empty
            lockVer = lockVer.encode("utf-8")
            ser.write(lockVer) #write to Arduino
            time.sleep(10) #wait for lock to open
        #time.sleep(5)
```

Here is the Arduino code:

```
void loop(){
  char pass[6]; 
  char lockVer = '0';
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Door(sensorValue);
  door = warning;
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    lockVer = Serial.read();
  }
  if (lockVer == '0'){
    while (door == 0){
        while (i < 6){
          char key = customKeypad.getKey();
          if (key){
            pass[i] = key;
            lcd.write('*');
            i++;
            if (i == 6){
              delay(500);
              lcd.clear();
              i = 0;
            }
           }
           Serial.println(pass);
           Serial.flush();
        }
      //delay(5000);
      //scaleCheck;
    }
  }
  else{
    Lock(unlock);
    delay(5000);
    Lock(lock);
    delay(5000);
    }
  }
```

My hope is that the variable lockVer would change from 0 to 1, and this change would be identified by the Arduino, causing the linear servo to activate and move into the unlock position, wait 5 seconds, and move back to the locked position. Instead, the Arduino code ignores the change, and keeps looking for keypad input. The keypad code is confirmed to work, and the variable lockVer does change from 0 to 1 in Python, just not in Arduino.

I can post the rest of the code if anyone needs more context, but I am running out of things to try, and I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: looks like your arduino code is getting stuck in the "while(door == 0)" loop. Change that to an if condition and your code should work as intended.

Comment: Hello Nitro, thanks for replying to me! This was the exact problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please mark the answer that I have given as the correct answer so that the next set of people who view this thread know that it is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your arduino code is getting stuck in the "while(door == 0)" loop. Change that to an if condition and your code should work as intended